# Count the number of ways to decompose integer n into sum of 4 squares

Tags: c++, algorithm

For integer `N (0 <= N <= 10^7)` and answer the following question.

> How many ways to decompose integer n into sum of 4 squares?

Example:

> Given the integer n in the file `NUMBER.INP`

**NUMBER.INP**
3

> We will write the results to the file `NUMBER.OUT` is the number of ways to decompose the integer n into the sum.

**NUMBER.OUT**
4

The result is 4 because:

```
3 = 0^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2
3 = 1^2 + 0^2 + 1^2 + 1^2
3 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 0^2 + 1^2
3 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 0^2
```

Comment: I suppose this is a competitive programming question and there is a time limit? ...

Comment: Hint: Can you compute number of ways to decompose `n` into sum of 2 squares? What about 3?

Comment: Time limit is one second.

Comment: I don't know yet :(

Comment: Show your effort

Comment: I used backtrack but over time

Comment: You *might* be able to solve this with a knapsack DP. Brute force is obviously not going to work without some really good pruning.

Comment: I can't slove it, it hard with me. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply two theorems to solve this problem.

1. [Lagrange's_four-square_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem)
2. [Jacobi's_four-square_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem)

the second theorem states that

> The number of ways to represent n as the sum of four squares is eight times the sum of the divisors of n if n is odd and 24 times the sum of the odd divisors of n if n is even

So ultimately you problem is reduced to finding the divisors. Which can be done on O(sqrt(n)) time. Since you have multiple queries this can be further optimized in O(log(n)) time using [sieve of eranthoses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)